# Use two sources in an AWS-CodePipeline pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, continuous-delivery, aws-codepipeline

I have a specific case which I'm not sure if it's possible with AWS CodePipeline. I'm not able to find any information about such scenario in the documentation and google.

So I would like to know if I can set two sources in a pipeline (it could be in the same stage or different stages).

Here is my use case:

- I would like my pipeline to start when a file (a specific object) is modified in my s3 bucket
- When this file changes and the pipeline is triggered, I would like to clone a codecommit repository and then process the build and other stages.
- On the other hand, when there is a commit on the master branch of my codecommit repository, I would like the pipeline to start and build my sources.
- So The pipeline should be triggered either when the change comes from s3 or codecommit
- I don't want to version the s3 file in my codecommit repository because it should be encrypted and used by others teams than dev team working with the git repository
- And any time my pipeline starts either if it's from the s3 bucket change or the codecommit push, I should source the commit from the repository for build purposes.

Is it possible to use two source actions in a pipeline as described above? If yes, how to achieve this?

Answer (score 19):

Yes. It is possible to have two sources for an AWS CodePipeline. Or many for that matter.  The two sources have to be in your first stage.

[image]

Then in your build phase properties, you need to tell it that you are expecting two sources.

[image]

Then tell the build project which is your primary source.  This is going to be the one that you want your build project to execute the codebuild.

[image]

From your buildspec or from any scripts you call, you can then access the source directories by referencing:

- $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR_SourceOutput1
- $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR_SourceOutput2

Just replace SourceOutputX above with what you call your output from the source stage.

I found the following link with more information:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-multi-in-out.html

Comment: If you aren't seeing CodePipeline trigger on the second GitHub repository, check to see that a GitHub webhook was created in the repository. I found this out the hard way. The GitHub user you use to authenticate with AWS *must* have admin privileges on the second repository you add *when* you set up the pipeline.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, CodePipeline allows multiple source actions in a single pipeline. A change in either source will trigger a pipeline execution. The thing to know is that every pipeline execution will pull the latest source for both actions (not just the one with a change that triggered the pipeline execution).

Comment: can I proceed like this ?:

     - Create my first pipeline stage : the source
     -  In that source stage : create one source action type with my first source (lets say s3 bucket)
- Create a second source action type for  this same source stage with my second source (codecommit repository)
    - Then create the build stage, which will use the last output artifact
    - And follow the standard workflow for the rest of the pipeline execution

Would that work? In which order?

Comment: Yes, you can incrementally add actions and stages to your pipeline subject to two constraints: stages can't be empty and CodePipeline requires two or more stages.

Comment: i cant get two sources working in codepipeline with CDK.... build only sees content of the primary source.

Comment: Can one of the sources NOT trigger the pipeline?

Comment: @jenson-button-event Yes, you have to uncheck "Start the pipeline on source code change" on your source action