# How to Deploy multiple Lambda Functions using single code pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-codepipeline

I have tried to deploy multiple lambda functions which are in multiple code commit repository
to deploy it using single code pipeline.
But I am unable to do it.

```
I tried https://medium.com/hatchsoftware/setting-up-ci-cd-for-lambda-functions-using-aws-codepipeline-880567769dde
```

But It is working for single lambda not for multiple lambdas

Comment: The article is behind a pay wall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To handle multiple repositories using a single CodePipeline, you can specify one source action per repository. Please also have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61763968).

Looking at the CodePipeline setup in the article you mentioned, it would be possible to process the artifacts from all the source actions in the same CodeBuild project ([docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-multi-in-out.html)), so there is no need to add additional build actions. Same goes for the deploy stage: Assuming you are using CloudFormation, you can manage all Lambda functions in the same stack, so you only need one deploy action.

Answer (score 2):

> in multiple code commit repository to deploy it using single code pipeline.

As @berenbums pointed out my original answer was not fully correct. CodePipepine (CP) supports multiple sources as exemplified in AWS docs:

- [AWS CodePipeline integration with CodeBuild and multiple input sources and output artifacts sample](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-pipeline-multi-input-output.html)

Comment: Actually a single CodePipeline **source action** can only be associated with a single branch of a single repository. However, a CodePipeline can have multiple source actions, so it would be possible to set up one source action per repository. Here is a related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61763968).